# Spring Cloud Stream Binding Consumer properties are not working

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to override the default values to the below listed values in consumer properties, but I don't see the changes are getting reflected. I was hoping that I will get an exception as the service won't be able to process 500 messages in 10 seconds. Not sure, if this the right way to configure.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
        kafka:
            bindings:
              test-topic:
                consumer:
                  configuration:
                    max.poll.records: 500
                    max.poll.interval.ms: 10000
```

Comment: Where are you looking to see if these are applied? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your code and debugging the configuration process?

Comment: The Kafka client jar spits out an INFO log showing the actual applied properties; search for `ConsumerConfig values:`.